# Are the users posting not-an-answer answers informed what they're doing wrong?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

When I flag an answer as "not an answer" and it is accepted by a moderator, is the user who posted the answer notified about this? Does this notification contain an explanation why the answer was removed?

I am asking because I never know if I should post comments explaining that the answer was flagged and what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flag itself doesn't send out any notification.

If the answer is deleted or converted to a comment and the moderator who does that leaves a comment, the user will be notified of that comment.

I typically leave comments on most not-an-answers that I remove if they're recently posted. There's not much point in commenting on something that's over a year old, for example.

You can certainly leave a comment of your own, especially since there may be enough time for the user to see it before a moderator sees your flag. You can use a [handy userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) to store and reuse the most common comments. It comes with a few pre-loaded that you can use right away, but I like to edit them to make the language more "mine".

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The user will be able to see a link `Why was this deleted?` under the deleted answer if they go to the page directly. It also indicates if something was converted to a comment, instead of just deleted.

No direct poke is sent their way, however. But, if it's an answer they really cared about, they'll see why. Additionally, moderators can leave a comment prior to deleting that the user will see. We do this when helping new users, or chronic 'non-answerers'.