# What happens to users posting non-answers?

Tags: support, flags, deleted-answers, not-an-answer

Building on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115976/are-the-users-posting-not-an-answer-answers-informed-what-theyre-doing-wrong), what happens to users who post 1 or more answers that are flagged as non-answers and/or deleted?

Are they punished or restricted in any way?

Comment: I really hope not. Especially since Link only answers were fine at one point.

Comment: I think there's an automatic answer ban, parallel to the [question ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi) for asking terrible questions.

Comment: In my experience, the majority of non-answers are posted by new users, few of whom ever do anything more on the site. Rarely have I seen people posting more than two non-answers, so I don't know that a system for penalizing people that do this would catch all that many users.

Comment: Rubber hoses and soap in socks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a user posts too many answers that are downvoted and/or deleted, they can be [banned from posting further answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90851)

If a new user posts spammy or abusive answers, or it is otherwise clear that the user is making no effort whatsoever to learn what the site is about and how to use it properly, their account is typically "destroyed," taking all of their content with it.

If a user is posting bare links or other promotional material, but they have made even the slightest effort at contributing useful material or being productive on the site, they are warned instead, and their off-topic posts are deleted.